# Replace operator new and delete seems to affect C libraries

Tags: c, gcc, new-operator, c++98

I globally replaced new/delete to ensure my objects are aligned correctly for fast computation:

```
#ifdef __WAND__
target[name[new.o] type[object] platform[;GNU/Linux]]
#endif

#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cstdio>

void* operator new(size_t count)
    {
    void* buffer;
    int res=posix_memalign(&buffer,64,count);
    if(res==0)
        {
        printf("Allocated %zu bytes at %p\n",count,buffer);
        return buffer;
        }
    return NULL;
    }

void operator delete(void* buffer)
    {
    printf("Free buffer %p\n",buffer);
    free(buffer);
    }

void* operator new[](size_t count)
    {
    void* buffer;
    int res=posix_memalign(&buffer,64,count);
    if(res==0)
        {
        printf("Allocated %zu bytes at %p\n",count,buffer);
        return buffer;
        }
    return NULL;
    }

void operator delete[](void* buffer)
    {
    printf("Free buffer %p\n",buffer);
    free(buffer);
    }
```

After getting a lot more than expected on `stdout`, I checked who did call my `new` operator. Here is what the backtrace may look like:

```
#0  operator new (count=4) at new.cpp:13
#1  0xb753a87d in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#2  0xb7420e96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#3  0xb7420f31 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#4  0xb73cb710 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#5  0xb7422dc5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#6  0xb7422ec4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#7  0xb7467da0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
#8  0xb7ed02cc in fgDisplayMenu () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
#9  0xb7eced1c in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
#10 0xb7ed285f in fgEnumWindows () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
#11 0xb7ecf26e in glutMainLoopEvent () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
#12 0xb7ecfabc in glutMainLoop () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
#13 0x0804acaf in GlutWindow::mainLoopRun () at glutwindow.cpp:28
#14 0x080496db in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffeb34) at main.cpp:28
```

So why is the low-level graphics library calling my `new` operator? Can there be any other reason (some black magic) than the this library is written in C++ (i thought most such things were written in C or assembly) using new/delete instead of malloc/free?

Comment: "glutwindow.cpp" is of course a C++ source file that will also use ::operator new.

Comment: The are no operators `new` and `delete` in C.  Suggest changing tag

Comment: @HansPassant. Yes, but one call only.

Comment: Why not write a library in C++?  Well written C++ can be as fast as C and for some applications the benefits of object oriented programming and templates make for much easier maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low level libraries might be written partially or completely in `C++`. There is no other reason (black magic) to call the new operator.